# Remove empty double quotes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

[image]

How can i remove those empty double quotes that displayed inside the `<div class="nav-modal-main"></div>`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $('.nav-modal-main').html('');

Comment: With this solution the hole container get empty. I would like to keep the childrens->.msg-container and remove only the double quotes

Comment: Make another temporary (hidden) div in DOM. Add all `.msg-container` divs and any other div that you would like to preserve in this temporary hidden div. Empty `.nav-modal-main`. And reattach all divs in hidden div to their original parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace()`

```
var tempStr = $('.nav-modal-main').text();
tempStr.replace(/"/g,  '').replace(/,/g,'').trim();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
var tempStr = $('.nav-modal-main').text();
$('.nav-modal-main').text(tempStr.replace(/"/g,  '').replace(/,/g,'').trim());
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-modal-main">
",   "
  
  Testing
</div>
```

Comment: Gives me an error->Uncaught TypeError: $(...).replace is not a function

Comment: @Vasileios See I've updated my answer, check the working example also.

Comment: @Vasileios Glad to see that, All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option without jquery:

```
document.querySelector('.nav-modal-main').firstChild.textContent = null
```

you can check it out [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjZjXm)